# Rails admin how to display the more than 100 records in dropdown list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-admin

Railsadmin while displaying records maximum 100 only.If we want to customize the dropdown 
more than 100 records?

Answer (score 1):

In config/initializers/rails_admin.rb needs to be changed to

```
 RailsAdmin.config do |config|
      config.model 'User'  do
        field :user_id, :enum do
        enum_method do :get_all_users 
       end
      end
    end
 end
```

In models/user.rb

```
def get_all_users
   User.all.map{|x|[x.id,x.name]}
end
```

You could use pluck instead of all.map